# AngularJS: Using If condition in text input

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have an input type as text to select dates and I want that Its default value should be the earliest amongst the JSON data having following structure:

```
testData=
{
  "name":"ABC", transactions:[
  {"tranid":01,"trandate":"01/02/2010"},
  {"tranid":02,"trandate":"01/02/2012"}
  ]
}
```

I want to iterate through transactions and Dispay the earliest date in the text input(i.e 01/02/2010)

Please assist how to do it in angular.

Comment: mean you want the lowest date to be printed in the textfield

Comment: testData.transactions.trandate[0];

Comment: I want to iterate throught the transactions data and find the lowest date and display it

Answer (score 0):

Hi please see here: [http://jsbin.com/reyog/1/edit](http://jsbin.com/reyog/1/edit?html,js,output)

```
function finderliest()
  {    
        angular.forEach(testData.transactions, function(transaction){

       if($scope.erliest === undefined || transaction.trandate < $scope.erliest ){
             $scope.erliest = transaction.trandate;

      }
    });

  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var len=testData.transactions.trandate.length;
if(len>0)
{
      for (i=0;i<len;i++)
     {
        for (j=1;j<len;j++)
        {
            var dateone=testData.transactions.trandate[i];
            var datetwo=testData.transactions.trandate[j];

            //(use this logic or else logic whichever you like) http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8911c4/how-to-compare-two-dates-using-javascript/


        }
      }
}
```